# What is a promise object?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

Having started learning Ember, I get confused whenever there is a reference to Promise Object. I am aware of objects e.g. instance of class X or a JSON object.  For instance, when somebody says that method `m` returns a JSON object then I know to expect key-value pairs. How do I relate this understanding to promise objects? Is a promise object a value (could be array, string, number, JSON object, etc.)?

What should I expect if a method returns a promise object?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: True, but JSON syntax is frequently referred as JSON object isn't? When you create an object from JSON data, people refer it as JSON object

Comment: Json Object - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp003.htm

Comment: Yes, incorrectly so. You mentioned JSON objects having key-value pairs, i.e. _properties,_ but object literal syntax is just one way to create an object. Regarding your link: yes, and if you'd read the article I linked to you'd see such objects acknowledged and _they're not what you were talking about in your question._ That doesn't invalidate my point.

Comment: P.S. If you check Stack Overflow's [info page about promises](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/promise/info) you'll find a bunch of explanatory links.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I am not invalidating your point, merely trying consolidate and clarify my understanding.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: whats wrong with that?

Comment: The citation was in response to terminology in question, not about programming.

Comment: @nnnnnn of course there is such a thing as a JSON object - might want to check the specification.

Comment: @Bala are you familiar with any other programming languages that have generics or templates? Basically if you have a value `T` then a `Promise<T>` is a proxy for that value.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - which specification? The JSON specification makes it pretty clear that JSON is a string format used for data transmission... Obviously various languages have classes/objects that handle JSON serialisation/deserialisation, but that's not the same thing as the "JSON object" that people incorrectly think JavaScript objects created with an object literal are.

Comment: @nnnnnn JSON is as much of a string format as JavaScript is a string format. JSON is a language used to describe data - it very clearly has a notion of an object. What you're protesting (rightfully) is that people call JavaScript object literals inside JavaScript code JSON objects which is indeed incorrect - those are JS object literals not JSON objects. However, `{"a":3}` is most definitely a JSON object in the JSON language - see the spec or http://json.org/ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A promise is a new Object type of EcmaScript 6 (ES6), for which there are numerous [polyfills and libaries](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations) (i.e. implementations for ES5 JavaScript engines), and allows (among other benefits) to get out of the infamous *callback hell*, and to write and read asynchronous code easily.

A promise can have one (and only one) of these three status:

- **pending**
- **fulfilled**
- **rejected**

If the promise is rejected or fulfilled, it also has a **settled** status.

Basically, it is an object that has a `then` property (amongst others), which is a `function` that takes at least one function as a parameter, and can take two: the first one will be invoked if the promise returns a *fulfilled* status, and the second one will be invoked if the promise returns a *rejected* status

The `then` function returns itself another promise, so promises are chainable.

Promise objects are rather more complicated than what I just wrote here, but it was just to give you a start.

BTW, you may have used a promise-like object (note the *-like* suffix) if you use jQuery : `$.ajax()` returns a promise-like object (those are called **thenable**s) that has a `done` (and a `then`) property which is a `function` that accepts a function as the parameter that *seems like* a `fulfilled` function (which normally takes only one argument). Promise objects also may have a `done` function property (not standardised, AFAIK, but almost all the polyfills and the libraries implement it), which acts like a then function, only it does not return a promise (hence the name: if you are done with the promise, then use `done()`, but if you need to do somehting with the result of the promise, use `then()`).

e.g.: you may have seen or written something like this:

```
$.ajax({url: '/path/to/html/piece'})
    .done(function(data) {
        $('whateverSelector').html(data);
    });
```

But what jQuery calls promises, even if they are **thenable**s, does not fulfill the [promise spec](https://promisesaplus.com/).

Comment: Good answer to a badly asked question. It might be worth to mention what the purpose of `.done` is. Also - promise like objects are called by the spec "`then`ables" - since your terminology is spot on in the rest of this answer you might want to mention that.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my answer according to (I hope) your remarks.

Answer (score 5):

Promise object is what it's name says it is - a promise. In frontend frameworks like Ember and Angular promise is an object returned by an asynchronous call. This call instead of blocking the whole system returns you a promise, which will eventually contain the data the asynchronous call returns.

Promises have an event called resolve, which is triggered when the response come. That's why promise objects have method usually called `then`. You can use it like this (after Ember.js docs):

```
var promise = fetchTheAnswer();

promise.then(fulfill, reject);

function fulfill(answer) {
  console.log("The answer is " + answer);
}

function reject(reason) {
  console.log("Couldn't get the answer! Reason: " + reason);
}
```

When your request is fulfilled the promise will call the method `fulfill` with `answer` (response) as an argument, and when the request is rejected (ie. when the resource doesn't exist) it will call method `reject` with `reason` (error) as an argument.

Such objects are similar to objects in other OO languages like java - they contain both data and methods you can call on them.